# Нужно ли в данной функции проверять параметр size?

Tags: c, malloc

Задание: реализовать функцию, которая выделит и вернет "чистую" область памяти. Выделяемая память заполняется 0. Если выделить память не удалось вернуть NULL (Allocates(with malloc()) and returns a “fresh” memory area. The memory allocated is initialized to 0. If the allocation fails, the function returns NULL).

Вопрос: нужно ли в данной функции проверять параметр size?

```
void    *memalloc(size_t size)
{
    void    *array;

    array = malloc(size);
    if (array == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    memset(array, 0, size);
    return (array);
}
```

Из документации на функцию malloc:

If size is  0,  then malloc()  returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully passed to free().

P.s. я считаю что переменную size проверять не нужно, т.к. по заданию условие "Если выделить память не удалось вернуть NULL" выполняется.

```
if (array == NULL)
        return (NULL);
```

Пожалуйста аргументируйте ответ !

Comment: попробуй выдели память,а потом free()

Comment: Нужно ли проверять параметр `size` зависит от постановки задачи. Если нужно - то нужно. Если не нужно - то не нужно. У вас в постановке задачи ни слова не сказано о том, что делать, когда `size` равно 0. Что такое "выделить память не удалось", если `malloc(0)` вдруг вернет не null? Это "удалось" или "не удалось"?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "условие выполняется", если в документации на `malloc` ясно сказано, что `malloc(0)` может вернуть не null?

Comment: Под "условие выполняется" я имею ввиду что если array != NULL то нам удалось выделить память даже если size = 0. Если же array == NULL то функция вернёт NULL и условие тоже выполнится. Могу ошибаться, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Условие - если выделить память не удалось вернуть NULL

Comment: @Nikolay: Ну так, если в задании требуется, чтобы ваша функция в отношении `size` полностью повторяла поведение `malloc`, то тогда и проверять `size` не надо. Тогда не ясно, откуда возник вопрос. Что вас смущает в вашем коде?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанию, Ваша функция должна делать тоже, что и функция [calloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

Детали ее реализации можно найти [здесь](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Allocating-Cleared-Space.html) (компилятор: GCC).

```
PTR
calloc (nelem, elsize)
  size_t nelem, elsize;
{
  register PTR ptr;  

  if (nelem == 0 || elsize == 0)
    nelem = elsize = 1;

  ptr = malloc (nelem * elsize);
  if (ptr) bzero (ptr, nelem * elsize);

  return ptr;
}
```

В стандарте ситуация, когда malloc передают 0, описана так (ISO/IEC 9899:2011, 7.22.3):

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is
>   implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the
>   behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the
>   returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Соответственно, поведение функции malloc будет зависит от используемого компилятора. Чтобы избежать этого - наложите ограничения в более высокоуровневом коде (т.е. *Вашем*).